# Prevent directory variable expansion

Tags: bash, tmux

`tmux` seems to override my default bash behavior. Suppose `export someDir=/path/to/it`, then in my shell

1. Hitting tab on `cd $someDir` automatically adds a front slash, `cd $someDir/`. On `tmux` it does nothing, and prints `$someDir` (literally).
2. Hitting tab on `cd $someDir/` lists the contents. On `tmux` it expands the variable. Only two more tabs show the contents.

I have double checked both are running Bash, and if pertinent, this is my config:

```
set -g status-style bg=black
set -g status-style fg=red
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

How can I reproduce the original behavior?

**More info**

@Kusalananda's comment made me think that `tmux` might be overriding my completion settings. Hitting `complete` in a normal shell lists just 2 git wrappers. `tmux` shows a ton.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the `bash` shell both in and outside `tmux`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Good question - checked and yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using tmux, but what I found (with horror) is that it's re-enabling the "programmable completion" of bash that I had long commented out in `/etc/bash.bashrc` -- thence the puzzling behavior you observed.

That's because tmux is exec'ing bash as a login shell (with `argv[0]` set to `-bash`) which is causing it to source `/etc/profile` and then `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`.

You have too options:

a) make the completion behavior the one you like in both login and non-login shells by editing `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`

b) convince tmux not to run a login shell, eg. by

```
set -g default-command "/bin/bash"
```

in `.tmux.conf`

Comment: That is CRAZY. Are there any repercussions you are aware of? I found this, which seems to be no: https://superuser.com/questions/968942/why-does-tmux-create-new-windows-as-login-shells-by-default#970847

Comment: LOL. I'm using gnu screen, which does NOT start login shells by default. Neither does the terminal emulator (mlterm). Maybe I should check my head ;-)